# Unable to import pytorch_lightning on google colab

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, pytorch-lightning

I have done the following:

```
!pip install pytorch_lightning -qqq
import pytorch_lightning
```

But get the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-d883b15aac58> in <module>()
----> 1 import pytorch_lightning

----------------------------------9 frames------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/apply_func.py in <module>()
     26 
     27 if _TORCHTEXT_AVAILABLE:
---> 28     from torchtext.data import Batch
     29 else:
     30     Batch = type(None)

ImportError: cannot import name 'Batch' from 'torchtext.data' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchtext/data/__init__.py)
```

What could the issue be?

Comment: did you try installing using `pip install`??

Comment: Yes, if you look at the first line.

Comment: https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/6210

Comment: try the following `!pip install torch pytorch-lightning`

Comment: @AviThaker https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/6415 as well

Answer (score 12):

As said in Issue #6415 on [Github](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/6415), try installing from the GitHub.
It worked for me.

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning
import pytorch_lightning as pl
print(pl.__version__)
```

Output:

```
1.3.0dev
```

It seems that the error is coming from [Issue #6210](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/6210) and they say it was fixed. I guess it wasn't uploaded to PyPi.

Comment: For Colab users, then you can solve this by reinstalling (or upgrading) pytorch_lightning version 1.3.0dev without any dependencies  except fsspec.
 `!pip install git+https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning fsspec --no-deps --target=$nb_path `

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that was possible.

Answer (score 5):

Example working env: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GSCd3Gz3EOQIln3v065VKWKbB3_F8xqK?usp=sharing

Can you try after restarting your env.

```
!pip install torchtext==0.8.0 torch==1.7.1 pytorch-lightning==1.2.2
```

```
import pytorch_lightning as pl
print(pl.__version__)
...
```

There appears to be a bug that has not hit pip yet with pytorch lightning not referencing the newest torchtext.

[image]

Comment: fails, with an OSError

Comment: Could you send the error? I am unable to replicate. You can also try with !pip install pytorch=1.7.1 in addition to the other commands.

Comment: /usr/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    362 
    363         if handle is None:
--> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    365         else:
    366             self._handle = handle

Comment: Also 1.7.1 doesn't exist

Comment: !pip install torchtext==0.8.0 torch==1.7.1 pytorch-lightning==1.2.2

Comment: Then restart your env

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229669/discussion-between-avi-thaker-and-pythonsnek).

Answer (score 3):

You can try this command, I encountered the same problem and was able to fix the problem.

```
!pip install --upgrade pytorch-lightning
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem arises from the *pytorch-lightning==1.1.x* versions. Version above *1.2.x* fixes the problem

But taking the latest version as in *PythonSnek*'s answer resulted in some other bugs later on with the checkpoints saving. This could be because the latest version - `1.3.0dev` is not still in development.

Installing the *tar.gz* of one of the [stable versions](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/releases) fixes the problem

```
!pip install https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/releases/download/1.2.6/pytorch-lightning-1.2.6.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

Late, but if you are having similar difficulties with PyTorch Lightning Bolts you can solve it at the time of posting by making use of the same strategy:

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/lightning-bolts
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing the following installations solved my problem

```
pip install pytorch-lightning==1.4.4

pip install omegaconf -U

pip install hydra-core --upgrade
```

Source of Solution: https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/7110

Answer (score 0):

may be you should upgrade your pytorch-lightning. My version is 1.4.0, when I upgrade it to 1.5.10. The error disappears.