# import pytorch_lightning returning transformers.__spec__ is None

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch-lightning

I am running:

```
!pip install pytorch-lightning==1.2.8 --quiet
!pip install transformers==4.5.1 --quiet
```

when I run:

```
import pytorch_lightning
```

I am getting this error:

```
 transformers.__spec__ is None
```

If a update both libs to latest version, I get stuck in this code:

```
sample_batch = next(iter(DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=8, num_workers=2)))
```

When following this guide:

```
https://curiousily.com/posts/multi-label-text-classification-with-bert-and-pytorch-lightning/
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to import pytorch\_lightning on google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66538407/unable-to-import-pytorch-lightning-on-google-colab)